# Foreach xml server response

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have some questions about `foreach`.
I do a request with `curl` and I receive a response in `XML` like:

```
<HotelList>
<HotelSummary id=848484>
<hotel>prova</hotel>
<address>via bho</address>
<thumbNailUrl>/hotels/1000000/530000/526200/526198/526198_38_t.jpg</thumbNailUrl>
</HotelSummary>
</HotelList>
```

How can I change every

```
<thumbNailUrl>/hotels/1000000/530000/526200/526198/526198_38_t.jpg</thumbNailUrl>
```

to

```
<img src="$$server$$/hotels/1000000/530000/526200/526198/526198_38_t.jpg>
```

Is it possible to do this with `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

you mean like:

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($your_xml_response);
foreach($xmlObj->HotelSummary as $hotel) {
  $imgSrc = "$$server$$" . $hotel->thumbNailUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not with a `foreach` loop alone.
Yes, using a `foreach` loop is good way to start.

You could for example iterate over an SimpleXml object. Please refer to the [PHP SimpleXML manual](http://php.net/book.simplexml.php) to get started with the basics. Always also have a look at the comments, as they provide a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 option for solving it

In foreach

```
foreach($xmlarray as $key => $val)
{   
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($val);
    if(in_array($fileInfo['extension'],array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","tiff"))
    {
        $val = "<img src='".$serverpath.$val."' >";
    }
}
```

OR

```
foreach($xmlarray as $key => $val)
{   

    if(in_array( substr(strrchr($val,'.'),1),array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","tiff"))
    {
        $val = "<img src='".$serverpath.$val."' >";
    }
}
```

Comment: For the checking image extension and then add the image tag